# Sum the value of array in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

This is my array

```
[{:amount=>10, :gl_acct_id=>1, :alt_amount=>20}, {:amount=>20, :gl_acct_id=>2
, :alt_amount=>30}]
```

i want result

```
[{:amount => 30}] or {:amount = 30}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use `inject` to sum all the amounts. You can then just put the result back into a hash if you need to.

```
arr = [{:amount=>10, :gl_acct_id=>1, :alt_amount=>20}, {:amount=>20, :gl_acct_id=>2, :alt_amount=>30}]    
amount = arr.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:amount]} #=> 30
{:amount => amount} #=> {:amount => 30}
```

Comment: thank you @sepp2k this is very useful. in the answer above we have to name the key - what if we want the sum for all the keys - (i.e. we don't want to name them individually - do you know how we would solve that?)

Comment: I have the same issue, my hash is [2, #<BigDecimal:7f29fe6164b0,'0.1256E4',9(18)>, 4, #<BigDecimal:7f29fe6163e8,'0.281E4',9(18)>, 3, #<BigDecimal:7f29fe6162a8,'0.24E4',9(18)>] and I wish to sum the values which have no name.

Answer (score 91):

Ruby versions >= 2.4.0 has an [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_rc1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method. So you can do

```
arr.sum {|h| h[:amount] }
```

Comment: probably the best answer IMHO

Comment: But this returns

    30

and not the desired result

    [{:amount => 30}] or {:amount = 30}

Comment: @tvw Which is trivial once you get the sum. Also this answer was posted 6 years after OP had asked the question. So my intension was to help any one who comes here with a similar problem. :)

Answer (score 73):

`array.map { |h| h[:amount] }.sum`

Comment: and while using rails, could be shorter: array.sum {|h| h[:amount]}

Comment: This creates a temporary array, which can be avoided.

Answer (score 13):

This is one way to do it:

```
a = {amount:10,gl_acct_id:1,alt_amount:20},{amount:20,gl_acct_id:2,alt_amount:30}
a.map {|h| h[:amount] }.reduce(:+)
```

However, I get the feeling that your object model is somewhat lacking. With a better object model, you would probably be able to do something like:

```
a.map(&:amount).reduce(:+)
```

Or even just

```
a.sum
```

Note that as @sepp2k pointed out, if you want to get out a `Hash`, you need to wrap it in a `Hash` again.

Comment: @mittag can you tell me what should be a better object model ?? so i can use this one ... a.map(&:amount).reduce(:+)

Comment: @krunal: Most basic example: `Foo = Struct.new(:amount, :gl_acct_id, :alt_amount); a = [Foo.new(10, 1, 20), Foo.new(20,2,30)]; a.map(&:amount).inject(:+) #=> 30`

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks! Missed that one.

Answer (score 5):

why not pluck?

```
ary = [{:amount=>10, :gl_acct_id=>1, :alt_amount=>20}, {:amount=>20, :gl_acct_id=>2, :alt_amount=>30}]

ary.pluck(:amount).sum

# for more reliability
ary.pluck(:amount).compact.sum
```

Comment: Only rails thought, from 5.0 and above https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck

Comment: This would require unnecessarily iterating over the array several times

Answer (score 4):

```
[{
    :amount=>10,
    :gl_acct_id=>1,
    :alt_amount=>20
},{
    :amount=>20,
    :gl_acct_id=>2,
    :alt_amount=>30
}].sum { |t| t[:amount] }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's usually better to __explain__ your answers, rather than just posting code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

If we are having only a single element in all the hashes in a array and also keys were different ?

Here is the solution I found:

Sum of the values:

`x = [{"a" => 10},{"b" => 20},{"d" => 30}]`

Solution:

`x.inject(0){|sum, hash| sum+= hash.values.join.to_i }`

Also we can do:

`x.inject(0){|sum, hash| sum+= hash.values.sum }`

Answer (score -2):

```
total=0
arr = [{:amount=>10, :gl_acct_id=>1, :alt_amount=>20}, {:amount=>20, :gl_acct_id=>2, :alt_amount=>30}]
arr.each {|x| total=total+x[:amount]}
puts total
```

Comment: that is mostly equivalent to this one-liner: ```total = arr.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum += hash[:amount]}```