# Better way to sum values in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to sum values in an array hashes and I found a way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728014/sum-the-value-of-array-in-hash)

but it sure seems like there should be a more elegant way in Ruby.

Here is what works;

```
sales = [{"sale_price"=>210000, "deed_type"=>"Warranty Deed"}, {"sale_price"=>268300, "deed_type"=>"Warranty Deed Joint"}]

total_sales = sales.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash["sale_price"]}
```

The totals line is not very readable.  It would be nice if something like this worked;

```
total_sales = sales.sum("sale_price")
```

Is this just wishful thinking or am I overlooking a better solution?

Comment: Its a correct way to do it. Crude way you can do: sum = 0;sales.each{|x| sum=sum+x["sale_price"]};sum

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tin Man, I wasn't aware of the code review site.

Comment: "It would be nice if something like this worked". This is Ruby, add the `Enumerable#sum` you'd like and problem solved. Maybe you should call it `Enumerable#hash_sum` though, Ruby is a OOP language and `sum` should be calling methods.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I like using the map/reduce metaphor like so:

```
total_sales = sales.map {|s| s['sale_price']}.reduce(0, :+)
```

The reduce method is a synonym for the inject method, I find the name inject to be somewhat confusing with the memo component.  It has another form I use above to take the initial value and a reference to a method call used for the combination/reduction process.

I think the overall pattern of mapping the values and then reducing them to an aggregate is well known and self-documenting.

EDIT: Use symbol :+ instead of proc reference &:+

Comment: Great answer. The `Symbol.to_proc` (`&:`) used as the second reduce argument is around an order-of-magnitude slower than just writing a plain block `.reduce(0){|t,i| t + i }`, only worth noting if your array may contain large numbers of elements. See http://www.igvita.com/2008/07/08/6-optimization-tips-for-ruby-mri/ #5.

Comment: Wow, good to know.  It's amazing what you find when you profile code or dig under the covers.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I am still trying to get my head around map/reduce which is probably why the intent of the code is not intuitive to me.  Do you have any recommendations for a good explanation?

Comment: The way I read the code is: map a list of sales objects onto a list of sale prices and then reduce them by combining the prices into a total.

Comment: Under Rails, you can just go `sales.map {|s| s['sale_price']}.sum`. If `s` was an object with a `sale_price` method, it could be even terser: `sales.sum(&:sale_price)` :D

Comment: You don't need to explicitly state the 0, so the end can just be `.reduce(:+)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it work:

```
sales = [{"sale_price"=>210000, "deed_type"=>"Warranty Deed"}, {"sale_price"=>268300, "deed_type"=>"Warranty Deed Joint"}]

def sales.sum(by)
  inject(0){|sum, h| sum + h[by]}
end

p sales.sum("sale_price") #=> 478300
```

Note this `sum` method (sum_by might be a better name) is not defined on Array, but only on the specific sales array.