# Reducing an array of hashes into new hash

Tags: ruby

I have an ActiveRecord relation that looks something like this:

```
[  
  {  
    timestamp: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
    user_id: 3,
    organization_id: 1,
    all_sales: 10,
    direct_sales: 7,
    referred_sales: 3,
  },
  {
    timestamp: Wed, 03 Oct 2018 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
    user_id: 3,
    organization_id: 1,
    all_sales: 17,
    direct_sales: 8,
    referred_sales: 9,
  },  
  {
    timestamp: Thu, 04 Oct 2018 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
    user_id: 3,
    all_sales: 3,
    direct_sales: 3,
    referred_sales: 0,
  }
]
```

What I'd like to do is create a "sum" of all the keys pertaining to sales (for our purposes here, I don't need `timestamp`, `user_id` or `organization_id`, so basically, I'd like to end with something like this:

```
{
  all_sales: 30
  direct_sales: 18
  referred_sales: 12
}
```

Is there an elegant ruby-ish way of doing this? I could easily create a set of variables for each sales category and augment them as I iterate over the original relation, but I wanted to see if the community had a cleaner method. In reality each of these hashes have far more than 3 relevant keys and so I fear that approach will get messy very quickly.

Edit: I also have checked out some other answers to similar questions here on SO (for example: [Better way to sum values in an array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654720/better-way-to-sum-values-in-an-array-of-hashes/14654841)), but ideally I wouldn't iterate so many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |obj, hash|
  %i[all_sales direct_sales referred_sales].each do |sym|
    hash[sym] = hash[sym].to_i + obj[sym]
  end
end
```

It's one iteration, you can write the nested loop as 3 different lines, but it's a bit cleaner this way in my opinion.

Note: calling `to_i` while getting previous value of `hash[sym]` as initially it is `nil` and `nil.to_i == 0`. Alternatively, you can initialize all unknown counts with 0, like this:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |obj, hash|
  %i[all_sales direct_sales referred_sales].each do |sym|
    hash[sym] += obj[sym]
  end
end
```

Comment: `hash.fetch(sym,0)` is another option.

Comment: `arr`, `obj`, `hash` and `sym` are not great variable names. Remember to use ones representing your domain logic in actual code :)

Answer (score 5):

Since you're starting with an ActiveRecord Relation, you can use [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to calculate all the sums with SQL and have it return an array with your totals:

```
SalesModel.pluck('SUM(all_sales)', 'SUM(direct_sales)', 'SUM(referred_sales)')
#=> [30, 18, 12]
```

Comment: And if you're like me and don't like mixing SQL in your Ruby code. You can use `SalesModel.arel_table[:all_sales].sum` as replacement for `'SUM(all_sales)'`. The same goes for the other attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Or use functional approach with `reduce` and `merge` methods:

```
keys = %i{all_sales direct_sales referred_sales}
total_sales = items.map {|item| item.select{|key, _| keys.include?(key)}}
                   .reduce({}) {|all, item| all.merge(item) {|_, sum, value| sum + value}}

# total_sales
# => {:all_sales=>30, :direct_sales=>18, :referred_sales=>12}
```

Or little bid clearer approach for Ruby 2.5.0 or higher, thanks to @Johan Wentholt

```
items.map {|item| item.slice(:all_sales, :direct_sales, :referred_sales)}
     .reduce({}) {|all, item| all.merge(item) {|_, sum, value| sum + value}}

# => {:all_sales=>30, :direct_sales=>18, :referred_sales=>12}
```

Comment: If you're using Ruby >= 2.5.0 I'd recommend using [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Hash.html#method-i-slice) instead of [`Hash#select`](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Hash.html#method-i-select). eg. `item.slice(*keys)`

Answer (score 1):

Use Merge and Reduce function

```
value = arr.reduce do |h1, h2|
  h1.merge(h2) do |k, v1, v2|
    [:all_sales, :direct_sales, :referred_sales].include?(k) ? (v1 + v2) : nil
  end
end.reject {|_, v| v.nil?}

p value
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of more verbose other options (that can be rendered more DRY and general):

```
result = { all_sales: (array.sum{ |e| e[:all_sales] }), direct_sales: (array.sum{ |e| e[:direct_sales] }), referred_sales: (array.sum{ |e| e[:referred_sales] }) }
```

or:

```
result = array.each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |h, obj|
  obj[:all_sales] += h[:all_sales]
  obj[:direct_sales] += h[:direct_sales]
  obj[:referred_sales] += h[:referred_sales]
end
```

To be more DRY and general, starting with the array of the required keys

```
keys = [:all_sales, :direct_sales, :referred_sales]
```

The first becomes

```
keys.map.with_object(Hash.new) { |k, obj| obj[k] = array.sum { |e| e[k] } }
```

and the second:

```
array.each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, obj| keys.each { |k| obj[k] += h[k] } }
```