# Calculate sum of columns value in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to calculate the sum of the values in a column. For example:

```
@items = Item.find_all_by_cart_id(cart)
```

Item has column quantity. I want the sum of the @items quantity.

Comment: Have you tried using [inject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728014/sum-the-value-of-array-in-hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items_quantity = @items.map(&:quantity).sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@items = Item.find_all_by_cart_id(cart).sum(:quantity)
```

Comment: This is a a cleaner, model related way to do this.