# Sum of values inside Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have array like

```
[{:name=>"test 1",
  :sku=>"HG-22LR",
  :data1=>5,
  :data2=>5,
 },
 {:name=>"test 1",
  :sku=>"RF-22LR",
  :data1=>2,
  :data2=>2,
 }]
```

I need to combine the value of data1 and data2.

output like:

```
[
  {:name=>"test 1",
  :sku=>"HG-22LR",
  :data1=>7,
  :data2=>7,
 }
]
```

Comment: you can find your answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728014/sum-the-value-of-array-in-hash)

Comment: Does that array always look like that (just two elements with the same name and SKU)? Or is it possible that there are more elements in the array and potentially different names and SKUs?

Comment: spickermann, Yes it is possible that there are more elements in the array and potentially different names and SKUs

Comment: @sourabh I think the main question here - how to treat two sets of data that has the same name, but different SKU? Or is this completely impossible?

Comment: BroiSatse, we don't need to care about sku if the name is same then just need to combine all the data of both hash and make one hash

Comment: If they have the same name but different SKUs, how do you decide which SKU applies to the result?

Answer (score 1):

**data**:

```
data = [{:name => "test 1",
  :sku => "HG-22LR",
  :data1 => 5,
  :data2 => 5,
 },
 {:name => "test 1",
  :sku => "RF-22LR",
  :data1 => 2,
  :data2 => 2,
 }]
```

**possibilities**:

```
data.group_by{ |record| [record[:name], record[:sku]] }.map do |group, records|
  { 
    name: group[0], 
    sku: group[1], 
    data1: records.sum { |d1| d1[:data1] },
    data2: records.sum { |d2| d2[:data2] }
  }
end

 => [{:name=>"test 1", :sku=>"HG-22LR", :data1=>5, :data2=>5}, {:name=>"test 1", :sku=>"RF-22LR", :data1=>2, :data2=>2}]
```

or if you don't need to separate by SKU, and you want to join a list of SKUs :

```
data.group_by { |record| [record[:name]] }.map do |group, records|
  { 
    name: group[0], 
    sku: records.map { |d0| d0[:sku] }.uniq.join(','), 
    data1: records.sum { |d1| d1[:data1] },
    data2: records.sum { |d2| d2[:data2] }
  }
end

 => [{:name=>"test 1", :sku=>"HG-22LR,RF-22LR", :data1=>7, :data2=>7}]
```

if you don't like `#join`, you could use `#first`, `#last`, `#max`, `#min`, etc.